# Possible to change the CMD commands to the nix commands?

Tags: linux, bash, cmd, gnome

I am using a windows 7 machine and a)

```
Wondering why the commands of CMD are even different?
```

And b)

```
If it is possible to change the commands so that it behaves like linux
```

Comment: You're driving a Ford and complaining that it's not acting like a Mazda? They're completely different operating systems. Different commands are to be expected.

Comment: just buy a Porsche (Mac)

Comment: Dir versus ls though. That is just evil!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is that it's a different operating system! 
You can't change the CMD commands, but you can setup a unix/linux type shell environment in windows.

Your two main choices are:

- MSys - http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS
- Cygwin - http://www.cygwin.com/

I've used both and prefer msys, but both work just fine.

These will install programs and libraries to support them that you should be familiar with (bash, gawk, sed, grep, etc).

You'll also want to look at a decent terminal emulator:

- Console
- ConEmu

I prefer ConEmu, but again both work just fine and I'm sure there are other options out there too.
You don't need an emulator, but it's nicer than the normal command window

Answer (score 0):

Install [msys](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS) and you can mostly use unix commands.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible but you can install an environment like Cygwin:

```
http://www.cygwin.com/
```

Or install tools like Unxutils:

```
http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/
```

Even install a virtual system with VirtualBox:

```
https://www.virtualbox.org/‎
```